How to access a nested array inside of an API JSON response using React?
I am currently having troubles accessing the valus inside a nested array return from my API call.  My API repsonse is being ran through a couple filters prior to being passed to the table as the variable "dataPagedSortedAndFiltered"
when I  run a console.log
'console.log("Parameters: ", dataPagedSortedAndFiltered());, my data comes back in this format:
Parameters: 
    [{…}]
        0: 
            id: 33
            name: Upper Limits
            value: 1500
            ltm: Array(1)
                0: {ltmId: 104, ltmNumber: 3468}
                1: {ltmId: 110, ltmNumber: 3666}            
            type: Standard

I can easily access the id, name, value, and type values, but regardless whatever I tried to access the LTM values, I keep getting errors.  I am wanting to map through the ltmNumbers and display them in a comma separated list.
I have tried multiple ways to access the data, including calling to items["ltm"]["ltmNumber"], but to no avail.
here is my table so you can see how I am attempting this:
return (
    <TableContainer>
        <TableBody>
            dataPagedSortedAndFiltered().sort((a, b) => (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1).map((item, id) => (
            <TableRow key={item.id} >
                <TableCell>Name: {item.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Value: {item.value}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Type: {item.type}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {(() => {
                        if ((item.ltm).length === 0) { return ("None"); }
                        else {
                        return (
                        {item.ltm.map((item: any, index: React.Key ) ltm => (
                            <span key={index} > 
                                {ltm.ltmNumber}{index !== (item.ltm.ltmNumber).length - 1 ? ', ' : ''}
                            </span>);
                        }
                    })()}
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
    </TableContainer>
  );


can someone please show me what I am doing wrong so I can display a list of ltmNumbers?

you can do it like this :
            <TableCell>
                {item.ltm.length === 0 ? (
                    "None"
                ) : (
                    item.ltm.map((ltm, index) => (
                        <span key={index}>
                            {ltm.ltmNumber}
                            {index !== item.ltm.length - 1 ? ', ' : ''}
                        </span>
                    ))
                )}
            </TableCell>


This is perfect.  I just couldn't figure out he syntax to drill down into the  nested values and get them to display.  Thank You.!

I guess it is syntax?
{item.ltm.map((item: any, index: React.Key ) ltm => ...
should be
{item.ltm.map((item: any, index: React.Key ) => ...
what kind of error?

This question already has an accepted answer with the fix you're suggesting.

Since you are using typescript, it's better to provide some types for your code:
// type declaration
interface Item {
    id: number // or string (depends on your data)
    name: string
    value: number // or string
    ltm: {
       ltmId: number, // or string
       ltmNumber: number
    }[]
    type: string
}

function YourComponent() {
   const items: Item[] = await getItemsFromSomeJSON() // you get data from your json
return (
    <TableContainer>
        <TableBody>
            dataPagedSortedAndFiltered().sort((a, b) => (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1).map((item, id) => (
            <TableRow key={item.id} >
                <TableCell>Name: {item.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Value: {item.value}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Type: {item.type}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {
                        item.ltm.length ?
                        item.ltm.map((ltmItem, index) => ( // ltmItem type should be inferred as { ltmId: number, ltmNumber: number }
                            <span key={`${index}`} > 
                                {ltmItem.ltmNumber}{index !== ltmItem.ltmNumber.length - 1 ? ', ' : ''}
                            </span>);
                        : <p>None</p> 
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

